# jquery ajax - form serialization issue on query parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, forms

I am using jquery ajax to post a html form . This works fine with Chrome and not with Firefox . When I analyze the issue ,the query parameter "Accept=Apply" is not shown in Firefox dev tool (Params tab)but I could see the proper string is in debug statement which i have added. Can anyone help on this?

**Jquery :**

```
function postSettings() {
    var frm_data = $("#MyForm").serialize() + "&Accept=Apply";
    console.log("frm_data >>"+frm_data);
    var myobject = {"Accept":"Apply"};
    var testdata =$("#MyForm").serialize() + '&' + $.param(myobject);
    console.log("testdata >>"+testdata);
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://10.20.12.30/Update.cgi",
            data: frm_data,
            success: function (successData) {
                console.log("successData >>"+successData);
                } else {
                    console.log("errorData1 >>"+successData);
                }
            },
            error: function (errorData) {
                console.log("errorData2 >>"+errorData);
            }
        });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: quick suggestion, try adding 'Accept' as hidden field and try again?

Comment: Thanks ssilla . it worked . Great.

Comment: Great, Shall I post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure . Please . I will mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to do this would be adding it as a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="Accept" name="Accept" value="apply"/>
```

This way we can aviod passing it as query string and unexpected issues.